# Tic Tac Toe Game Doesnt end when row one complete

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have a tic tac toe game I made, I am not done yet, but I made it so that if I get the first three rows I win the game for X.

But for some reason it doesn't work. It prints out that I won, BUT it doesn't end the while loop and break out and finish the game.

What am I missing?

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Initialize Array to 9 elements.
// Set array elements 1 to 9 to specify locations for placement of X and O.
char ticTacBoard[9] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
// gameState will return 1 to 4. #1. PlayerXhaswon, #2. PlayerYhaswon, #3. Draw, #4. GameNotFinished.
int gameState = 0;
int choosePositionX = 0;
int choosePositionO = 0;

// Functions declared to run game.
// Checks for winners, draw and if game should continue.
int checkGameState (int gameState);
// Takes in users moves.
void makeMove ();
// Resets board when game finished.
void reset ();
// Prints the board to the user.
void printBoard ();


int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!" << endl << endl
         << "The goal of Tic Tac Toe is to be the first player to get three in a row on the grid." << endl << endl
         << "Please select 1 through 9 to select placement for your turn."<< endl << endl;

int gameState = 4;

        while ( gameState == 4)
        {
            printBoard();
            cout << "Player X please choose a position: ";
            cin >> choosePositionX; makeMove();
            printBoard();
            gameState = checkGameState(gameState);
            cout << "Player O please choose a position: ";
            cin >> choosePositionO;
            makeMove();
            printBoard();
            gameState = checkGameState(gameState);

       }



cout << " END";

return 0;
}

int checkGameState(int gameState)
{
    // Check Rows
    if(ticTacBoard[0] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[1] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[2] == 'X')
    {
        cout << "YOU WIN!" << endl;

        return 1;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[3] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[5] == 'X')
    {
        cout << "YOU WIN!" << endl;
        return gameState = 1;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[6] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[7] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[8] == 'X')
    {
        cout << "YOU WIN!" << endl;
        return gameState = 1;
    }
    else
        return gameState = 4;
}

void makeMove()
{
    if ( choosePositionX )
    {
        ticTacBoard[choosePositionX - 1] = 'X';
    }

    if ( choosePositionO )
    {
        ticTacBoard[choosePositionO - 1] = 'O';
    }
}

void printBoard()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            cout << ticTacBoard[3 * y + x] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are missing checking the vertical and diagnol rows as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never use the return value of checkGameState.  You probably want to either pass gameState by reference and return void, or do gameState = checkGameState(gameState).
If you do the former, then you change them all to `gameState = 1; return;`  If you do the latter, then you just change them to `return 1;`

Version passing by reference:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Initialize Array to 9 elements.
// Set array elements 1 to 9 to specify locations for placement of X and O.
char ticTacBoard[9] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
// gameState will return 1 to 4. #1. PlayerXhaswon, #2. PlayerYhaswon, #3. Draw, #4. GameNotFinished.
int gameState = 0;
int choosePositionX = 0;
int choosePositionO = 0;

// Functions declared to run game.
// Checks for winners, draw and if game should continue.
int checkGameState (int gameState);
// Takes in users moves.
void makeMove ();
// Resets board when game finished.
void reset ();
// Prints the board to the user.
void printBoard ();


int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!" << endl << endl
         << "The goal of Tic Tac Toe is to be the first player to get three in a row on the grid." << endl << endl
         << "Please select 1 through 9 to select placement for your turn."<< endl << endl;

int gameState = 4;

        while ( gameState == 4)
        {
            printBoard();
            cout << "Player X please choose a position: ";
            cin >> choosePositionX; makeMove();
            printBoard();
            gameState = checkGameState(gameState);
            if (gameState != 4) break;
            cout << "Player O please choose a position: ";
            cin >> choosePositionO;
            makeMove();
            printBoard();
            gameState = checkGameState(gameState);

       }



cout << " END";

return 0;
}

int checkGameState(int gameState)
{
    // Check Rows
    if(ticTacBoard[0] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[1] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[2] == 'X')
    {
        cout << "YOU WIN!" << endl;

        return 1;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[3] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[4] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[5] == 'X')
    {
        cout << "YOU WIN!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if(ticTacBoard[6] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[7] == 'X' && ticTacBoard[8] == 'X')
    {
        cout << "YOU WIN!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
        return 4;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to return the value of gameState though

Comment: I think you're confused about the difference between passing by reference and passing by value.
If you want to pass by value, just return an integer, and then in your main function use the return value.
What you're doing now is setting a local variable inside the function, and then returning it, but never using it.

Comment: Can you show me an example? I am not sure i really get it unless i see an example. Just a concept

Comment: In main():

`printBoard();`
`cout << "Player X please choose a position: ";`
`cin >> choosePositionX;`
`makeMove();`
`printBoard();`
`gameState = checkGameState(gameState);`

In checkGameState:

`{`
`cout << "YOU WIN!" << endl;`
`return 1;`
`}`

Hrm, you can't do large code blocks in comments? Doh!

Comment: Be sure to change all of the ones I didn't mention too... even if you don't need to, as per @sarnold comment below!

Comment: Okay it works but it still asks for player O turn and then it cuts the program. But i had to set gamestate = 4 before the while loop

Comment: Why is the player O still asking to go? Let me update my code aboev

Comment: You're not breaking out of the loop partway through if the first one wins.  I don't have edit permissions on your question or I'd fix the code to show you!  For the minimal change, you'd have to do if (gameState == 4) break; after X's turn

Comment: So should i put an if statement if it equals a certain thing it breaks out?

Comment: Yep. You have to have a way to break out after X's turn.

Comment: Glad I solved your problem!  You might want to accept the response if you don't want other people to show up though! =)

Comment: @Danalog: you can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8044538/edit) to include the code block.

Answer (score 1):

While I think [Danalog's answer is the bug you're tripping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044531/tic-tac-toe-game-doesnt-end-when-row-one-complete/8044538#8044538), do note that you should be checking the board for wins or losses after every move, rather than after every *pair* of moves -- if X places a third in a row, it's pointless to ask O to make a move as well.